# C, stack around variable f1 was corrupted

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, stack

hi i have this function

```
int printofarray(int *j,double *n)
{
int x,k;
k=*j;
if(n==NULL) {
printf("array was not created\n");
return 1;}

for(x=0;x<k;x++){
printf("%.2lf\n",*(n+x));}

return 0;
}
```

when i use it the output is like this

```
34.77
6114.05
410.70
```

but i want to write them this way

```
  34.77
6114.05
 410.70
```

idea how?

Comment: Please void feof(). It does not do what you expect it to do. Also learn about pointers : `p_x[x] = f1;`  is the same as `*(p_x+x)=f1;`, but easyer to read.

Comment: how to void feof i dont understand

Comment: You should be doing: `while (fgets(s1, sizeof(s1), fr) != 0 && fgets(s2, sizeof(s2), fr) != 0 && fgets(s3, sizeof(s3), fr) != 0 && fscanf(fr, "%d", &c1) == 1 && fscanf(fr, "%f", &f1) == 1 && fgets(s4, sizeof(s4), fr) != 0 && fscanf(fr, "%d", &c2) == 1) pz++;` spread out suitably over multiple lines.  Or put the input code into a function which reports on whether it was successful — to avoid the duplication (which is gruesome).  Always check each input operation; don't use `feof()` to do so.  Use `feof()` only to distinguish between EOF and error when something has failed.

Comment: Mixing two `fscanf()` calls with one `fscanf_s()` call is a bit odd. Not formally wrong, but inconsistent and consistency is important in programming.

Comment: thanks i havent noticed that fscanf_s()

Comment: can you help me with transfering between functions ?

Comment: The simplest way to transfer the data from one function to another is to change this function to return a pointer to float (`float *array(void)`, and then change the error returns to return a NULL pointer, and the non-error return to `return p_x`.  However, that leaves you without any knowledge of the size of the array.  You might be able to add a sentinel value (0.0 or -1.0, perhaps).  Otherwise, think about passing a pointer to integer as a function parameter and assigning the size to the integer the pointer points at: `float *array(int *size) { ...; *size = pz; return p_x; }`.

Comment: interesting. this is better then what i wanted to do. this is easier thanks but how i will print that prizes beacouse the want something like
xxxxxxxx3.4
xxxx55555.45
xxxxxx234.55
that prizes will be like print prize1\n prize 2\n but the numbers will be beneath and printed like they are ordered in file

Comment: Oops, typo. I meant *avoid* feof(). My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%lf` specifies to read a `double`, but you're trying to store the result in a `float`, which is half the size. The specifier for a float is just `%f` — or use a `double`; floats are fairly useless on modern general-purpose computers.

Answer (score 2):

Offhand, try %f instead of %lf for f1.   Edit:  %lf is for double.

Comment: yeah, OP prob trying to do %1f